# What fantasy book has a kid who turns evil and can move so fast he can pass through solid objects?

Tags: story-identification, books

This was a long time ago, but there were other kids with powers too, like a guy who could generate a force field, and a girl that could control any kind of energy from the kinetic energy of bullets to electricity to heat.  The one who can move fast passed his arm through a bomb to disarm it and lost his arm. He had a robotic one made to replace it.

Answer (score 4):

Got it. *[The New Heroes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Heroes)* series, specifically *[The Quantum Prophecy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quantum_Prophecy)*, by Michael Carroll.

> The story opens with a seemingly random battle among the many superhumans that inhabited the western world, set ten years ago at the foot of a gigantic tank that was on its way to New York City. During the course of this slugfest, the superheroes and supervillains all seem to lose their abilities.
>
> Ten years later, Colin Wagner and Danny Cooper, the children of these superhumans are discovering their abilities and they soon learn that they have also inherited their parents' enemies. The teenagers are kidnapped in order to calibrate the machine that might take away their powers and stop a war that was prophesied by Danny's father, the man once known as Quantum. Danny was believed to be the cause of this war, and so he allowed the supervillain known as Façade to take his place to let Maxwell Dalton record his visions of the future as he broke down. They had hoped to avert it by stripping the world of superpowers ten years ago, but the machine was destroyed and Danny's powers continued to manifest. The new machine would be unstable, and potentially kill hundreds of thousands of people, but it was a risk they were willing to take. With the help of old heroes, including the frozen in time Renata Soliz (Diamond), they stop this from happening and have those behind the plot taken away. By the end of the book, they realise how much risk is involved in becoming superhuman, with Danny's arm now missing, his real father dead, and many lives irrevocably changed.